# How to clean up a thread within seconds before killing it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, thread-safety, request-cancelling

I have a utility which will access the database and clean the garbage files. this is a console application which is being called from another application.

I have a thread from the main thread which will do the tasks while the main thread will be in a loop to check if cancel of the utility has been called.

The functions in the thread call a different dll which takes time. Now, is there any way that when I cancel the thread. Even if it is inside the function, it gets notified to stop immediately and rollback any changes done to the database?

My application is a windows based application and is written in c++. I have tried using **TerminateThread()** function from Windows but the problem is that is does not allow to do clean up on the thread.

Comment: fyi, re `TerminateThread`  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=91811

Comment: Yes, That why I am trying to find a alternative where I can stop the thread execution immediately but, kill only after kill. Even if it is inside one of the funcitons it should stop executing and start cleanup process.

Comment: The same logic applies. What if you tell the function to 'stop executing' after taking a lock on some datastructure?

Comment: I think you can't do it If you are not able to change the dll code to accept a terminate order. You can execute TerminateThread() but you can't know if all resources will be released in that dll.